# Straighten out jagged contour filled pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I am producing a contour-filled plot of piecewise planes with pgfplots. Some regions of the space are perfectly straight lines, whereas others (top left) are giving jagged edges. I assume this has to do with how the contour mesh (or patch? I can't quite work out the difference) is formed, but I cannot figure out how to alter this to produce the desired uniformity (i.e. the straight lines like in the middle and right regions).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
                    declare function={ReLU2(\x,\y,\theta)=max(0, cos(deg(\theta))*x + sin(deg(\theta))*y - 1/3) + max(0, -cos(deg(\theta))*x + sin(deg(\theta))*y - 1/3);},%
                   ]
       \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
            xlabel=$x_1$,
            ylabel=$x_2$,
            view = {0}{90},
            colormap/viridis,
            ]
            
          \addplot3 [domain=-1:1,
              domain y = -1:1,
              samples = 50,
              samples y = 50,
              contour filled = {number=10}
              ] {ReLU2(x,y,pi/4)};    
              
       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Jagged lines in top left]

I have also tried to use the `\pgfplotsset{contour/handler/.style={/tikz/smooth}}` command to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Nice filled contour plot]

This image:

is made from your original unmodified code. First it is compiled to a .pfd and to make an image, I use:

```
convert -density 500 FilledContour.pdf -resize 500 FilledContour.png
```

`convert` is from ImageMagick: https://imagemagick.org

Comment: I use overleaf to generate TeX, is there a way to use a similar method there? (Both the built-in and native pdf viewers give the same behaviour)

Comment: No - to use `convert`, you need ImageMagick. I can not tell you which, if any, pdf viewers support the needed features. Please upvote/accept answers.

Comment: I originally accepted the alternative answer as it seemed more general, but it turns out this one is definitely more general and works for all of my "resolution" issues, not just this particular one! In fact, one can use` \documentclass[tikz, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}` in the preamble to get the desired effect without needing to go through the terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is viewer dependent. -the manual warns about this. All the examples for `contour filled` in the manual looks terrible for me in mac preview.
You can repeat your plot and only show the "good" side:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
                    declare function={ReLU2(\x,\y,\theta)=max(0, cos(deg(\theta))*x + sin(deg(\theta))*y - 1/3) + max(0, -cos(deg(\theta))*x + sin(deg(\theta))*y - 1/3);},%
                   ]
       \begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
            xlabel=$x_1$,
            ylabel=$x_2$,
            view = {0}{90},
            colormap/viridis,
            ]
            
          \addplot3 [domain=1:-1,
              domain y = -1:1,
              samples = 50,
              samples y = 50,
              contour filled = {number=10},
              ] {ReLU2(x,y,pi/4)}; 
          \clip (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);   
          \addplot3 [domain=-1:1,
              domain y = -1:1,
              samples = 50,
              samples y = 50,
              contour filled = {number=10},
              ] {ReLU2(x,y,pi/4)};                  
       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2D filled contour plot]

Comment: Thank you for this! Could you clarify a bit further exactly what clip does? More precisely, how particular is this solution to these planes? I have also been trying to smooth out contour lines on a Gaussian line contour-fill which appears similarly jagged. Would a similar approach work there?

Comment: `\clip` does nothing more than hiding part of what comes after. Everything after `\clip (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);` is not draw unless it is inside the  rectangle with corners `(0,-1)` and `(1,1)`.